# Getting the max from two combined columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the value from all accounts in use, using the combination of two columns (Year and month) to get the right period.

The data table looks like this:

| Account | Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2015 | 1 | 11501 |
| 1000 | 2016 | 1 | 11111 |
| 1000 | 2016 | 10 | 11610 |
| 1000 | 2017 | 1 | 11701 |
| 2000 | 2014 | 12 | 22222 |
| 2000 | 2017 | 1 | 21701 |
| 3000 | 2015 | 1 | 33333 |
| 4000 | 2016 | 1 | 44444 |

Table: AcBal

[image]

I've tried to make an query, but somehow, I cant quite get there...

```
Select Account, 
       Year, 
       Month, 
       MAX(((Year*100)+Month)) AS YearPeriod, 
       Value 
from  AcBal 
where YearPeriod <= 201601 
group by Account, Year, Month, Value 
order by Account, Year
```

If I use "where year <= 2017", then I get a result, but with multiple hits for each accout. I only want one result for each account.

Wanted result:

| Account | Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2016 | 1 | 11111 |
| 2000 | 2014 | 12 | 22222 |
| 3000 | 2015 | 1 | 33333 |
| 4000 | 2016 | 1 | 44444 |

How can I achieve that?

Comment: please provide sample data and expected outcome. And also do not use an image to provide the sample data but something we can copy/paste

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: I will try to add the sample data. Isn't used to the input system in this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` like the following query

```
Select TOP (1) WITH TIES
        Account, [Year], [Month],  [Year]*100+[Month] AS YearPeriod , Value 
from AcBal 
where [Year]*100+[Month] <=201601   
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY [Year]*100 +[Month] DESC)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/DUPJ25770

Comment: This gives the result I am looking for! Thank you! I'll have to study "with ties".

Comment: @HaraldBang Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING:

```
Select Account, Year, Month,  MAX(((Year*100)+Month)) AS YearPeriod , Value 
from AcBal 
group by Account, Year, Month, Value 
Having MAX(((Year*100)+Month)) <=201601 
order by Account, Year
```

Comment: This also gives duplicate answer for account 1000 with Year 2015 Month 1 ant Year 2016 Month 1.